# C++ dll loses reference to windows.h when upgrading from .NET4 to .NET 4.5

Tags: c++, .net, dll, visual-studio-2013

I have a solution that I am upgrading from .NET 4 to .NET 4.5.  In that solution, I have a C++ project that gets compiled into a .dll which other projects in the solution use.  As part of the upgrade, I've upgraded Visual Studio from 2010 to 2013.

At a high level, the error I'm receiving is `Cannot open include file: 'windows.h': No such file or directory` from within the C++ project's `stdafx.h` (it has the call `#include <windows.h>`).  I have searched the internet and can confirm that the Windows 8.1 SDK is installed on my local machine.

I have had a look at my include directories, and `$(WindowsSdkDir)include` is there, as well as `$(WindowsSDK_IncludePath)`.

I can't seem to sort this out.  When upgrading a project from .NET 4 to .NET 4.5, why is the `windows.h` dll getting lost, and how can I set the project back into a stable state?

Comment: You might want to look at this guy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12748896/cannot-open-windows-h

Comment: It is not a DLL, it is an .h file.  The version of .NET is irrelevant to native code.   The compiler can't find the file, sounds like the VS2013 install did not go well.