# Unreal Engine 4.10.1 can't compile Visual Studio 2015 project

Tags: c++, compilation, visual-studio-2015, project, unreal-engine4

I recently installed the most recent version of UE on my Windows 7 and made a new empty C++ project. After creating the project it gave me an error saying it failed to compile. I opened the project in VS to manually compile it and this is the output I got.
I looked online but got no answers.

EDIT: I use these headers with no issues when compiling non-UE projects.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: RPG, Configuration: Development_Editor x64    ------
1>  Performing 7 actions (2 in parallel)
1>  [2/7] Resource PCLaunch.rc
1>C:\Program Files\Epic Games\4.10\Engine\Source\Runtime\Launch\Resources\Windows\PCLaunch.rc(10): fatal error RC1015: cannot open include file 'windows.h'.
1>
1>  PCH.RPG.h.cpp
1>C:\Program Files\Epic Games\4.10\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Public\HAL\PlatformIncludes.h(5): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'new': No such file or directory
1>  [3/7] Resource ModuleVersionResource.rc.inl
1>C:\Program Files\Epic Games\4.10\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Resources\Windows\ModuleVersionResource.rc.inl(3): fatal error RC1015: cannot open include file 'windows.h'.
1>
1>  -------- End Detailed Actions Stats -----------------------------------------------------------
1>ERROR : UBT error : Failed to produce item: C:\Users\Jack\Documents\Unreal Projects\RPG\Binaries\Win64\UE4Editor-RPG.dll
1>  Total build time: 3.64 seconds
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.MakeFile.Targets(37,5): error MSB3073: The command ""C:\Program Files\Epic Games\4.10\Engine\Build\BatchFiles\Build.bat" RPGEditor Win64 Development "C:\Users\Jack\Documents\Unreal Projects\RPG\RPG.uproject" -rocket -waitmutex -2015" exited with code -1.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

The part that really confuses me is that it apparently can't open new.h and windows.h though Visual Studio has no problem opening the file when I check where they were included.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot open Windows.h](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12748896/cannot-open-windows-h)

Comment: I've used that header outside of UE projects without issues.

Answer (score 2):

After creating an Unreal Engine project you may face errors like:

- "fatal error RC1015: cannot open include file 'windows.h' "
- "fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'new': No such file or directory".

To fix it open your project (not EU4 project) properties/VC++ Directories.

If you see empty fileds like "Include Directories", "Library Directories" then click on the combo box on the right side and choose "inherit from parent or project defaults".
Then compile the project again.

Images below:

[Default project template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwJnG.jpg)

[Build errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EH2XF.jpg)

[choose inherit from parent or project defaults](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9xHH.png)

[image: After project fix]