# Set up Visual Studio for Unreal Engine 4.12.4

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, visual-studio-2015

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 community and Unreal Engine 4.12.4. 
I created some c++ classes, I can open them and I have them attached to the appropriate process. All seems to be fine but I can't compile them - I get a lot of errors (60, sometimes 400+) from the files "my class name".generated.h and "my class name".generated.cpp. I tried this one here, found on another thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34552036/unreal-engine-4-10-1-cant-compile-visual-studio-2015-project).
Those errors are: expected an identifier, #define syntax, sytax error, undeclated identifier, is not a class or namespace name and so on.
I would appreciate any advise.

Comment: have you tried doing the compiling in the unreal editor to see if you get same errors? because it might just be some sort of internal libraries or packages that you don't have in VS15

Comment: I did, it just said "compile failed, try manually", I guess that means in VS

Comment: upon exiting the reopening the project, it asks if I would like to rebuild it now. If I say yes, it tried but fails and exits. If I say no, it just exits :(

Comment: i think i found a thread that might help you: https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/184845/could-not-be-compiled-try-rebuilding-from-source-m.html

Comment: i think that is more or less a similar issue

Comment: wait wrong link: https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/230500/basic-c-template-does-not-compile.html

Comment: if you check the accepted answer the includes of windows libraries might be the solution you need

Comment: Just tried it, creating a new c++ class in UE editor, failed to compile. Then I went to VS where I could open the solution. I went to project>properties>VC++ Directories and at the Include and Library directories I chose "inherit from the...." that was the only option besides "edit" in the dropdown menu. Still no luck :(
EDIT: I might add, I did NOT modify anything else there and I had no "instead of" option like in the solution mentioned.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I made a zip file from the project. It is a small one, intended for practice only. If anyone has the time and patience to check it, it might help more than my description.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B33RFc9jZBV5OEtrZWd6TlZEUTA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: did you try purging your intermediate, saved, and binary directories? After that let your modules rebuild.

Comment: no but I found this was due to that I had az UE 4.9 project upgraded to 4.12. The 4.12 worked just fine :D