# Visual Studio doesn't recognize Unreal Engine

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unreal-engine4

I'm a student in Videogame Development, and just starting out looking at Unreal.
And no, none of my teachers know anything about this.
I have installed Unreal Engine 4.13 and Visual Studio Community *2013* now 2015.
I'm trying to make a C++ project using Unreal Engine (using blueprints is out of question so [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34552036/unreal-engine-4-10-1-cant-compile-visual-studio-2015-project) didn't help)
Now, when I make a basic C++ project, Visual Studio shows the following error message:

> Unsupported
>   This version of Visual Studio is unable to open the following projects. The project types may not be installed or this version of Visual Studio may not support them. 
>   For more information on enabling these project types or otherwise migrating your assets, please see the details in the "Migration Report" displayed after clicking OK.
>        - UE4, "C:\Users\Gebruiker\MEGA\Unreal\Disposable\Intermediate\ProjectFiles\UE4.vcxproj"
>        - Disposable, "C:\Users\Gebruiker\MEGA\Unreal\Disposable\Intermediate\ProjectFiles\Disposable.vcxproj"
>
> No changes required
>   These projects can be opened in Visual Studio 2015, Visual Studio 2013, Visual Studio 2012, and Visual Studio 2010 SP1 without changing them.
>        - Engine, "Engine"
>        - Games, "Games"
>        - Disposable, "C:\Users\Gebruiker\MEGA\Unreal\Disposable\Disposable.sln"

Then my browser opens showing a Migration Report telling me that VS had an error with Project.vcxproj and UE4.vcxproj, although it copes with Engine, Games and Project.sln.
After this VS does show up without any further action, and it does automatically open *.h and *.cpp files for newly added classes in UE4.
Though it does edit and save these, it claims that all UE's code is wrong (with squiggles), and for compiling UE4 gives errors on pieces of code that apparently don't give errors on other's machines.

It would be much appreciated to be helped out, and I'm sure it would help others too who would have the same problem.

**EDIT**
[A screenshot of the problem and configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaOzb.png)

**EDIT 2**
[A screenshot of the Help -> About Visual Studio page, VS 2015 C++ highlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZMZL.gif)

Comment: I found a few things that should apparently work, but won't with me:  
Making a virtual property (eg: void Function() works but virtual void Function() doesn't)  
UFUNCTION(), with or without any or all arguments.  
Add the PostEditChangeProperty helper function.
In any of these cases it will suddenly refer to line 30 of the .cpp file which gives the premade SetupPlayerInputComponent-function, although I didn't change anything of the sort. Is this even related?

Comment: Did you install C++ support when you installed Visual Studio? It is not enabled by default. You could try repairing your installation by running setup again.

Comment: @rlam12 Yes, I did install Visual C++ support for Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I uninstalled VS2013, installed VS2015 with all additional options checked, made a blank, new project with Unreal with just VS2015 on my pc, and now everything works fine.

Perhaps my VS2013 installation was broken, deprecated or switching version wasn't a good idea, but I can work with VS in any case now.

Also thanks to jeevcat for mentioning it!

Answer (score 2):

Starting with both the Unreal Engine Editor and Visual Studio closed, right click your .uproject file and select `Generate Visual Studio project files`, and then launch visual studio from the .sln file.

Once Visual Studio is open check your Solution Configuration is set to Development Editor. Then go to `Debug > Start without Debugging` (or Ctrl-F5). If everything compiles and the Editor opens again then you're good to go.

Comment: I have followed all the steps, my project wasn't configured for Development Editor, now it is. I still don't see any files show up, I can't debug or anything in that direction and Ctrl+F5 still doesn't do anything. I've added a screenshot above.

Comment: I'm not sure you're still using the correct version of Visual Studio. Can you post a screenshot of the About window: Help > About Microsoft Visual Studio

Comment: Okay, uploaded at the bottom of the post.

Comment: After following the steps above, does the Solution Explorer still list the `UE4` and `Clueless` projects as incompatible? Try right clicking `Clueless` and selecting `Rebuild` to compile. [See the docs here for more information.](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Programming/Development/CompilingProjects/index.html#buildingtheproject)

Comment: Otherwise I think you might be having issues because you changed versions of Visual Studio half way. Try to create a brand new C++ project through Unreal Engine.

Comment: that worked, not for the ebove project because I had to develop it in time, so I simply worked in a text editor. But I already found that this worked for a new project. I'll mark this solved, thank you!

Comment: No worries. Glad you sorted it out.

Answer (score 0):

Install newer version of the Visual Studio. VS2013 is not the latest one, VS2015 is. [People report](https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/181179/engine-source-unavailable-in-vs-2013-pro.html) that even updating VS2013 from Update 2 to Update 4 helps resolving similar issues.

Comment: Okay, fully removed VS 2013, fully installed VS Community 2015 with every optional thing available, I do have some options (it opens .h and .cpp files, but can't recognize Unreal Code nor compile anything here, I do have VS context menu's op uprojects, VS does start up at project start but still doesn't recognize the project-files...)  I didn't get any further, sorry.